# Load multiple tables from one word sheet and split them by detecting one fully emptied row

Tags: r, datatable, dataset, detect, stringr

So generally what I would like to do is to load a sheet with 4 different tables, and split this one big data into smaller tables using `str_detect()` to detect one fully blank row that's deviding those tables. After that I want to plug that information into the *startRow, startCol, endRow, endCol*.

I have tried using this function as followed :

`str_detect(my_data, ‘’)` but the *my_data* format is wrong. I’m not sure what step shall I make do prevent this and make it work.

I’m using `read_xlsx()` to read my dataset

Comment: Can you add a sample input to your post? What does the data look like when imported into R

Comment: @Rohit  https://imgur.com/rkjH14x